# Compare Python arrays values

Tags: python, compare

When I try this code in python:

```
maxdrc=0
if(distancearray[0]<distancearray[1])
    maxdrc=1
```

I get a `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: first of all you omitted `:` after `if` statement  , but whats your full `SyntaxError`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if` conditions must end with a colon.

```
maxdrc=0
if (distancearray[0]<distancearray[1]):
    maxdrc=1
```

Incidentally, the parentheses are optional.

```
maxdrc=0
if distancearray[0] < distancearray[1]:
    maxdrc=1
```

Answer (score 0):

`:` is missing.

```
if(distancearray[0]<distancearray[1]):
    # code                           ^
```

Demo:

with SyntaxError exception

```
>>> if 1 and 11
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    if 1 and 11
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

Valid

```
>>> if 1 and 11:
...   print "in if"
... 
in if
>>>
```